"Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting" Building fails with Github pages with Jekyll, Minimal Mistakes
Hi i have developed a simple blog with jekyll and Minimal Mistakes, the blog works if i deploy it locally but when i try to build it as a github page it fails. In particular i get this error:
  Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'BAS-Tools/assets/css/main.scss':
                File to import not found or unreadable: minimal-mistakes. Load path: 
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0/_sass on line 2
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:123:in 
`rescue in convert': File to import not found or unreadable: minimal-mistakes. 
(Jekyll::Converters::Scss::SyntaxError)
Load path: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0/_sass on line 2

This is part of my gemfile
gem "minimal-mistakes-jekyll"
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
gem "webrick", group: :jekyll_plugins

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
end

this is part of the config file
theme: minimal-mistakes-jekyll
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-include-cache

atom_feed:
  hide: true

And i have @import "minimal-mistakes"; in the main.scss file.
I have tried almost every possible configuration that are explained in others forums. Can someone please help me?
